# Adding a mailbox filter to Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to add a simple mailbox filter to Gmail, and getting error 400.  The response text says that "Filter doesn't have any criteria" but of course I believe I do.  Here is the payload data:

```
{
"filter": [{
"id": "ABC12345-2",
"criteria": {
"from": "donald trump"
},
"action": {
"addLabelIds":  ["TRASH"]
}
}]
}
```

This is the URL that I am posting to:

```
https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/filters
```

There is no problem with authentication. I have tried it with and without the "id" field.  Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your actual script. So I'm not sure about the requirement of `{"filter": []}`. But when I saw [the official document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create), it seems that the sample request body for the endpoint of `POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/filters` is as follows, when your request body is used.

#### Sample request body:

```
{
  "id": "###",
  "criteria": {"from": "###"},
  "action": {"addLabelIds": ["TRASH"]}
}
```

> - `id`: string, The server assigned ID of the filter.
> - `criteria`: object ([Criteria](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters#Criteria)), Matching criteria for the filter.
> - `action`: object ([Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters#Action)), Action that the filter performs.

- In this case, even when `id` is not used, no error occurs.
- You can also test above at ["Try this API"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create).

#### References:

- [Method: users.settings.filters.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/create)
- [Resource: Filter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters#Filter)

Comment: With the "filter": [] coding I was just trying to emulate the json that Gmail puts out when I retrieve existing filters created in the Gmail UI.  This format allows multiple filters to be retrieved in a single call.  Apparently Gmail does not allow the same coding on import.  I was able to get it working by doing a single filter per call.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeff McKay Thank you for replying and adding information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.